# AWS EMR java sdk - withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-emr

I have a running cluster on EMR, it is in "starting" step.

Is it possible to edit it's parameter to change `withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` from `false` to `true` ?

I would like it to not die while I am adding the step. And maybe keep it alive for a while.

But at some point allow it to terminate and turn this setting back to `false`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options available to manage the life of the cluster,

1) KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps - at EMR layer, ie keep the cluster alive when there are no EMR steps to run

2) TerminationProtection - at underlying EC2 layer, available in EC2 as well, stop taking down the cluster

You can turn `on` and `off` either of the options to keep the cluster `on` when the step processing has failed. To do so,

**From Console, when creating a cluster (go to advanced options)**

- KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps: Enable `Auto-terminate cluster after the last step is completed` checkbox
- TerminationProtection: Enable `Termination protection` check

**Using API/SDK, when creating a cluster**

- [KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html): set `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` to `true`
- [Termination protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_SetTerminationProtection.html): set `SetTerminationProtection` to true

**Update:** Currently you cannot update a running cluster, you would have to terminate and clone the cluster (can even have the same name).

Comment: I found all those information online, but I can't find a code example on how to edit the value of `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` on a running cluster.

Comment: Can I with the `aws` cli tool ? I can always run bash from scala as a last resort ?

Comment: I am sorry, again, to my knowledge, you cannot do that, cli, sdk, api, web doesnt allow you to edit a live cluster.